# Reading multiple XML in a single file

Tags: python, xml

I need to collect multiple pieces of short XML from a variety of places, all with similar format, in Python.  The catch is that they will be presented to me all in one file:

```
<infodump>
   ...
</infodump>

<infodump>
   ...
</infodump>
```

and so on.  I can find many examples of parsing XML in multiple files (iterating over all the files in a directory, for example), and examples of merging into a single file (with such things as xmlmerge), but I have yet found nothing on parsing multiple examples in the same file.

I try the usual

```
tree = ET.parse("./id.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
```

but it chokes on the second XML in the file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\dlevey\PycharmProjects\reconcile\main.py", line 27, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\dlevey\PycharmProjects\reconcile\main.py", line 5, in main
      tree = ET.parse("./id.xml")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1218, in parse
      tree.parse(source, parser)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 580, in parse
      self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 25, column 0
```

I'd really rather not split them again into multiple files, or request that they are all sent as individual files, as some of them are coming from the source as a single file, and I'll be processing thousands of XML samples at once.

Comment: Your file makes no sense, it is *not* valid xml. Wrap the entire nonsense in a single root and it'll work

Comment: It's intended to be a compilation of otherwise XML snippets.  That said, wrapping seems to be the way to go.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like hinted to in the comments, your input is not well-formed ([see here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-documents) for details on well-formed vs valid xml) because it doesn't have a single root element.

The easiest way to solve this is to wrap the input in a root element before parsing.

Here's a simple example that wraps the input xml fragments in an `input` element...

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open("id.xml", "r") as input_file:
    content = input_file.read()

well_formed_input = f"<input>{content}</input>"

root = ET.fromstring(well_formed_input)

for elem in root.findall("infodump"):
    print(elem)
```

This prints the following output:

```
<Element 'infodump' at 0x0000020B5FFB8400>
<Element 'infodump' at 0x0000020B5FFB84A0>
```

Comment: I like this solution. It's very creative.

Comment: I *know* it is not well-formed XML; it is a *collection* of XML bits.  As it turned out, wrapping the whole thing in root tags allowed me to get at the data I needed in each piece.

Comment: @DonLevey - I know you know based on the comments, but I wanted to have a complete answer for future visitors that might've searched on your same exception. I wasn't just answering for you specifically. Glad you got it figured out though.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Daniel’s suggestion you can use a html parser:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Start tag:", tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("End tag :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Some data  :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed("""<infodump>
   ...
</infodump>

<infodump>
   ...
</infodump>""")
```

Output:

```
Start tag: infodump
Some data  : 
   ...

End tag : infodump
Some data  : 


Start tag: infodump
Some data  : 
   ...

End tag : infodump
```